# Upscale the original grid data and find the new data of the specified grid

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Using RegularGridInterpolator from scipy.interpolate, we perform bilinear interpolation to embed a 5x5 kilometer grid data into a 10x10 kilometer grid data.  but the original 5*5 kilometer grid will have duplicate longitude and latitude, resulting in an error that cannot be applied to the suite.

5x5 kilometer grid data (lon,lat), and has 6*366(example 4days) daily rainfall data.

The following is just an example, I have a total of 1311 5 *5 kilometer grids

> ```
>   LON LAT 2   3   4   5
> 0 120.85  21.9    0.0 2.2738  0.0 0.0
> 1 120.7   21.95   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
> 2 120.8   21.95   0.0 0.7928  0.0 0.0
> 3 121.6   21.95   1.7275  1.4371  0.0 0.0
> 4 120.7   22.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
> 5 120.75  22.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
> ```

10x10 kilometer grid for specified latitude and longitude.

The following is just an example, I have a total of 323 10 * 10 kilometer grid

```
    LON LAT
0   120.75  22.05
1   120.85  22.05
2   121.55  22.05
3   120.75  22.15
4   120.85  22.15
5   120.65  22.25
```

Expected new daily rainfall data for the specified grid.

The full file is available at the following link
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nsS1M_qFlxtPIfQyOTrBnXZIkmMJiYJQ?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally interpolation requires the new targets to be "inside" the original data.

I have plotted the original data points you provided and the new ones you desire to know the rainfall at.

[image: New and old points]

It seems like the new target points are by no metric "inside" the old data points (what inside means depends on how you interpolate but in this case it would be connecting the outer points with straight lines).

To be able to interpolate on the new points you need to have more original data which "covers" the locations in which you desire to interpolate.

Comment: However, I have a total of 1311 5*5 km grids and expect to interpolate to the specified 323 10*10 km grids, but when using the RegularGridInterpolator Package, I encounter an error for bilinear interpolation due to duplicate longitudes or latitudes.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example. If its a case of duplicates then there is something wrong in your dataset. How can the same position have two different rainfalls in the same day?

Comment: example data is in the link below
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nsS1M_qFlxtPIfQyOTrBnXZIkmMJiYJQ?usp=sharing